# Get a list of teradata databases via jdbc?

Tags: jdbc, teradata

I am using com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver

I need to get a list of all databases to display to the user. To do that I create java.sql.Connection and call the following:

```
connection.getMetaData().getSchemas()
```

This returns the list of all teradata databases. However I would like to exclude users from this list.

To make myself more clear. If we look at teradata database in Teradata Studio Express we can see a list of all databases. In the Details for a Database there is an attribute called Database Type. The value is either "user" or "database". I would like to get via jdbc all those databases with the "database" type.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: On the surface the trouble is that a user is a database in Teradata. The lone difference is that a user has a password. Therefore, a user's schema can contain objects just like any other database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Develop your own [GetSchema()](http://developer.teradata.com/blog/tomnolan/2012/03/how-to-determine-or-switch-the-current-database-using-the-teradata-jdbc-driver) method that queries the DBC.Databases view:

```
public static String getSchema (Connection con)
throws SQLException
{
 Statement stmt = con.createStatement () ;
 try {
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery ("SELECT DatabaseName FROM DBC.Databases WHERE DBKind = 'D'") ;
  try {
   rs.next () ;
   return rs.getString (5) ;
  } finally { rs.close () ; }
 } finally { stmt.close () ; }
}
```

If you want to be a little more discrete in the objects that are displayed then you can use additional logic to specify the [UseXViews](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T21105JD.java.txt) parameter in the connection string to return only those objects the user has been provision access to through explicit or implicit permissions.

*Links point to the web sites used to provide answer.*